# threading the same job to work on separate files

Tags: multithreading

I want to run a job on 10 threads to process 100 files. Each thread is supposed to work on separate file. When a thread is done it is supposed to pick the next file.

What I'm doing right now is basically going on a loop, kick off the job and make it run in the background (using &), wait for any process to end if the count of processes is greater than 10 and pick up the next file. It is working but is there a better to way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any better solution, as long as each file has to be processed separately.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off having each thread process its file, then try to pick up the next file itself. Maybe it won't matter in your current application, but the starting and teardown of threads is relatively expensive. Common practice is to keep a thread alive if it is otherwise just going to be replaced by a clone of itself.